# How Create a View Like the Default Android EditContact View?

Tags: android

Specifically, I'm curious about how they did the phone number entry part, where they can add additional phone numbers fields when the user clicks the little add button.  I initially thought that was done with a ListView, and I got a ListView to work, but the ListView scrolls independently of the rest of the screen, which looks bad.

So I was wondering what the best approach for something like that is?  Am I on the right track with the ListView and just missing something allowing me keep it from behaving like it's own scrollable container?  Perhaps a custom AdapterView or maybe just with a TableLayout dynamically adding rows?  I'm just not sure what would work the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contact editor is fairly hard to read through due to the super-duper overkill modularization of the editor activity. I would think a vertical LinearLayout where you just inflate the new view directly into it with [View.inflate][1] would work; alternatively just call the [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) method on the LinearLayout to add the edittext/layout to it.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context, int, android.view.ViewGroup)

Answer (score 1):

[The layout file for that activity](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/act_edit.xml;h=2a7171724857c00b30946e939b7844e8120486fd;hb=HEAD) indicates they are using a `ScrollView`, wrapped around a `LinearLayout`. Presumably, when they add another phone number, they are inserting a view in the appropriate spot in their `LinearLayout`. You are welcome to review [the source for the application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD) to find out more details about their implementation.